# Is it possible to have merchant account with different name in android developer?

Tags: android

My question is, I want to create one developer account with some company name but I want to associate merchant account to that with my name in android developer.
Is it possible to do so? Or should developer name and merchant account name be same?

Comment: Just try it for yourself.

Comment: I can't because if it is not possible then I have to pay 25$ again.

Comment: OK sorry :-). I think it's possible because I could choose a name for my merchant account. I could choose a company name and my own name.

Comment: I too think, it's possible :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's possible because I could choose a name for my merchant account. I could choose a company name and my own name.